# Trying to indent a json dump and then write to a file

Tags: python, json

I had this json dump which is not well indented and not readable when i just write into a file so to make it more readable I did this

```
 with open(responseFile, 'w') as outfile:
      outfile.write(dumps(loads(content), indent=4))
```

but now I get this Invalid \escape: error. Any suggestions ?

e.g. Content:

```
{"devices":{"device":{"customAssetNumber":"","deviceName":"Shamik\'s iPhone","deviceOwner":"","deviceStatus":"Active","deviceType":"Smartphone","emailAddress":"sray@xyz.com","imeiEsn":342342,"installedDate":"2014-03-04T09:14:58","lastReported":"2014-03-05T06:48:42","DeviceID":"ApplC39GMAR7DTD8","Status":"Enrolled","mailboxDeviceId":"","mailboxLastReported":"","mailboxManaged":"","manufacturer":"Apple","model":"iPhone 4S","osName":"iOS 7","osServicePack":"","ownership":"Not Defined","platformName":"iOS","sourceID":1,"udid":"","unifiedTravelerDeviceId":"","username":"sray","wifiMacAddress":""},"count":1,"pageNumber":1,"pageSize":1}}
```

Comment: Does `loads(content)` work on its own at all? Sounds like you have invalid JSON here.

Comment: It doesnt work. What can be done to repair the content ?

Comment: Fix the content so it's valid json

Comment: I dont have a control over the content. It comes from the server.

Comment: Can you show the content?

Comment: @raynaya: That depends entirely on the content you are trying to parse. Without seeing that we cannot help you with that.

Comment: "devices":{"device":{"customAssetNumber":"","deviceName":"Shamik\'s iPhone","deviceOwner":""}} 

Likethis. I guess the \' is the issue

Comment: Try `loads('{{{0}}}'.format(content))`

Comment: Hmm but it didnt work ! It has nothing to do with the "deviceName":"Shamik\'s iPhone" ? i mean is it valid json which load should accept ?

Comment: `\'` are just fine. In which way it didn't work? I tested it with both of your examples.

Comment: So now i have fixed the wrapping braces and i am getting a wrapped response but still the same error. so the content is now like this but still getting the same error. {"devices":{"device":{"customAssetNumber":"","deviceName":"Shamik\'s iPhone","deviceOwner":""}}}

Comment: @raynaya yes, after all, it seems that the escaping was the problem, and my testing was wrong. I've updated my answer. (Please use the usernames in the conversations, so that people receives the notifications about your replies).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [RFC-4627](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt), only `"`, `\` and Unicode sequences must be escaped inside the strings. A bit hackish way to fix that would be:

```
import re
re.sub(r'\\([^"u\\])', r'\1', content)
```

That should work since the `\` is not supposed to occur anywhere else in a valid JSON.

Comment: You might want to explain why you need all the braces, since it's not immediately obvious why you need so many.

Comment: @raynaya has since added the curly braces to the question, so your first statement does not make any sense anymore.

Comment: @exhuma yes, removed that.